# Char array operations

Tags: c, arrays, string

Can anyone please explain to me if I have two char arrays char array1[] and char array2[] to compare two strings in these two arrays,
what does this mean

```
if (array1[j] == array2[j-i])
```

and

```
if (array2[j-i] == '\0')
```

**I'm confused with the [j-i] == j and [j-i] == '\0' part.**
This probably is a very stupid question but I'm very new to programming.
Thank You

Comment: @chux I know that buddy, I want to know what does the [i-j] = [i] and [j-i]='\0' (empty string) mean in layman's terms. Thank You

Comment: The code is probably used to see if a substring is contained in a larger string. You are comparing the char located at the current location `j` with the char located at `i` characters before.

Comment: does [i-j]=[j] mean if string of array1[i-j] is equal to substring of another array say array2[j]? @vsoftco

Comment: No, it just compares one character. That piece is probably used in a loop, and whenever the condition is false, then you know the substring is not a part of the string. Or, if you reach `\0` (i.e. end of string), then the substring is a part of the larger string. Think how would you check whether a string contains a substring, and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: so [j-i] refers to a particular character in a string? @vsoftco

Comment: yes, it refers to the `[j-i]` position in the array `array2`. It's "glued" to `array2`, it's not a separate entity.

Comment: Yes. If you have the ith index of array1 correspond to the 0th index of array2. Then the (i+j)th index of array1 corresponds to the (0+j)th=jth index of array2. In other words, if you are at index k in array1, you need to subtract i from k to get to the corresponding index in array2.

Comment: Thanks a ton Adam, that's what was confusing me. I'm all set. @AdamSuskin

Comment: No problem! If you don't mind, could you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Making it clear for people new to the thread (in comments above)

Yes. If you have the ith index of array1 correspond to the 0th index of array2. Then the (i+j)th index of array1 corresponds to the (0+j)th=jth index of array2. In other words, if you are at index k in array1, you need to subtract i from k to get to the corresponding index in array2.

END OF EDIT

What do you mean by "what does this mean"?

In order to check if array1 equals array2, you can iterate through one of the strings and check for character equality:

```
int equals(char *array1, char *array2, int length) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        //make sure that the char in array1 is equal
        //to the char in array2
        if(array1[i] != array2[i])
            return 0;
        //if array1 is done, then you no longer need
        //to check (and you know array2 is done too 
        //from previous if statement)
        if(array1[i] == '\0'
            break;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Note that length should be the smaller of the two lengths of array1 and array2 to avoid a bad access to memory. You probably know which one that would be, but without more context, I cannot give a more specific answer.

Comment: I'm confused with the [j-i] == j and [j-i] == '\0' part.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Where are you reading this from?

Comment: if (array1[i] == array2[0]){
    for (j = i; ; j++)
    {
    if (array2[j-i] ==  '\0')  break;

Answer (score 0):

Here is you commented code,

```
 if (if(array1[i] == array2[0])   
     // you have 2 arrays of chars and here 
     // you compare char at position i in array1 to
     // char at position 0 in array2

 { for (j = i; ; j++) { if (array2[j-i] == '\0') break;
        // if they are identical 
        // you have a for condition inside the condition strictly 
        // nothing happens, and it breaks out of the for condition
        // when the char in 
        // array2 is the end of string '\0'
```